# How to configure multi tenancy in WSO2 API manager 1.4?

Tags: wso2

I've seen that the WSO2 API manager version 1.4.0 offer the multi tenant capability, but apart from creating a new tenant in the carbon dashboard how can I have the different store and publisher applications for the different tenants.

My expectation is that I can have two different looks for the two tenants (even just applying different theme to the jaggery application), but I'm loosing where do I have to configure the existance of the tenant and How can I operate as a admin@tenant1 or admin@tenant2 to publish and consume in the store the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different theme support is not available. But when you publish an API as a tenant, it will be available in that particular tenant store. 
If you create a tenant, it will be a tenant admin. And for that tenant, you can create tenant users with different permissions. (That is login as tenant from management console and create users/roles etc..)

Comment: I do not understand how a generic user will be able to know the list of the tenants in the store or how is possible to access the different tenant stores.  There are no examples on how the feature works. Any example post could be usefull

Comment: @LucaGioppo when we publish an API we could select visibility, which can be public or restricted to some roles. Here is  documentation, which might help you http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/API+Visibility

Comment: Important information @Ratha.. Would be great if the same is listed in WSO2 API documentation as well..

Comment: @wajidmehraj These info for AM 1.4.0 version and now we are about to release 1.8.0 mid of october. You can find latest info about tenants and stores in AM 1.7.0 doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publishing+to+API+Stores

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change the look and feel for each tenant. In multitenancy you can create multiple tenants and each tenant can publish their APIs, so that will affect and available to only that tenant.

You can log into publisher and store using tenant username and tenant password.